# Lambda Expression for Latest Date

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, lambda

Let's say i have a Model defined as: `Foo {Id, Date}`.

Is there a way to make a boolean lambda expression so that I could get the Foo with the latest date? something along the lines of `(f => f.Date IsLatest)`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
var latest = model.OrderByDescending(m => m.Date).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: The result would not be a `DateTime`.

Comment: See also MaxBy() in Jon Skeet's [morelinq](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) library

Answer (score 4):

To make an expression that determines if the date is the latest, you need to know the latest date, i.e.:

```
DateTime latestDate = items.Max(f => f.Date);

var latestItems = items.Where(f => f.Date == latestDate);
```

Another approach would be to sort the items:

```
var latestItem = items.OrderBy(f => f.Date).First();
```

Or use Aggregate:

```
var latestItem = items.Aggregate((d, v) => v.Date > d.Date ? v : d);
```

Comment: I think you might mean `Foo.Where(f => f.Date == latestDate);`  :)

Answer (score 3):

Given that you've not provided any information about the name of your entities (I'm assuming `foos` here); something like this:

```
var latest = foos.OrderByDescending(f => f.Date).FirstOrDefault();
```

And if there are *more than one* with the max date (I know you said 'the Foo with the latest...' but I don't know the resolution of your times here) than you'll actually be after something more like Guffa's answer.

Be aware that either solution will benefit massively from an index on the date column.  If there is no index and the table gets large?  Then it could be very slow.

Comment: I was thinking along the lines of something like foos.Where(f => f.Date IsLatest). I was actually trying my hand in the Specification Pattern and I need it to be a boolean expression.

Comment: Yes, but that's not even c# so it won't compile, I'm sure you know that, too.  I'm not convinced that there's any real *benefit* to be had in wrapping EF in this way, either.  Surely a shortcut method on your ObjectContext class 'GetLatestFoo' which does something like the above would be the simplest thing?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DateTime maxDate = FooCollection.Max(f=>f.Date)
```

Comment: "get the Foo with the latest date", not "get the latest date"

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code:

```
List<Foo> fooList = new List<Foo>();

// add the Foo instance in list here
// then apply following to take latest

fooList.OrderByDescending(p => p.Date).Take(1);
```